# Поведение UDF в Spark/Pyspark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Почему мы получаем результат из первой UDF, если в Spark/Pyspark, используются ленивые вычисления и по идеи мы должны получать вызов второй функции, а не первой при вызове метода show на DataFrame df1?

[image: Тест]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вычисление результатов - да, ленивое. Но план строится когда выполняется `spark.sql`, так что `df1` ссылается на первую функцию которая была связана с `functionD`, которая и будет вызвана при `.show()`.